# When you close the application, boolean not set to no

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase in the application. I want to record the user's status in the database, it is currently in the application or not. I use the code from the official document, which must ensure this task. When the application is opened, the value is set to NO, and then changed to YES. But at the close of the application as well as the transition to the background, the block is not called and the value does not change. Here is my code...

```
FIRDatabaseReference *connectedRef = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@".info/connected"];
[connectedRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    if([snapshot.value boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"CONNECTED");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NOT CONNECTED");
    }
}];
```

> 2017-01-17 13:36:38.203 Tricker[6293:817528] NOT CONNECTED
>
> 2017-01-17 13:36:40.863 Tricker[6293:817528] CONNECTED

The console comes the following information, which shows that the value changes after two seconds after the opening of the application with NO to YES. But nothing happens when the application is closed...

Prompt in what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing connection state and application lifecycle.

When it is active, the Firebase Database client will fire information about its connection state on the `.info/connected` path.

But when the app is not active, the client has no way of firing this information anymore. You will need to use regular [iOS application lifecycle events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3) to detect when the app becomes inactive.

[Recording the user's presence in the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence) works as a two-step process:

1. when the application starts you write a value to the database to signal that the user is online
2. **when the application starts**, you tell the database server to write another value to the database that signals that the user is gone.

Step 2 is accomplished by `onDisconnectSetValue`:

```
[presenceRef onDisconnectSetValue:@"I disconnected!"];
```

The trick is that you call this method early on, typically when your app starts. The write operation will be executed when the Firebase Database server detects that the client disconnected.

This disconnect can happen in two ways:

1. when the client closes the connection explicitly
2. when the the socket that the server uses to communicate with the client times out

When your app crashes, you're in situation 2. In that case it can take a few minutes before the server detects that the client is gone, since you're waiting for a socket to time-out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You close the app means ? two things possibility

1. User can put app in Background : 
   Here you can set a NSUSEDefault value like :

> - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
>
>   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO
>     forKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
>     synchronize];
>
>   }

2. User can remove app from background :

> - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
>
>   ```
>      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];
>   ```
>
>   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
>
>   }

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know how to operate these functions, and tried to use them. But, unfortunately, when an application crash, then the value will not change, and other users will see that this user is online

Comment: @SashaTsvigun Your application should not crash. If it crashes, your code stops.

Comment: Hay @SashaTsvigun this code does not have any thing so that your app crash. Your crashing in some different position. try to rectify where these are happening or paste a code what exactly cause crash.